# Reference for Wang tile

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, tiling

I am working on projects in solving ground state of generalized Ising models. One recent work involves tiling with basic tiles that filled the whole lattice. For example, we could obtain results:
[image]

Every row corresponds to one constructible structure with basic tiles being "Generating configurations of the structure".

The resulting structures could be shown as followed:

[image]

9 and 12 are more complicated (can be periodic or aperiodic) shown as followed:
[image]
[image]

I realize (with the help of community), this is actually related to Wang tiles. So the first few steps I wish to approach this problem are looking into all established theorems on Wang tiles. Could someone suggest some relevant reference?

(PS:From engineering respective, I think we (in engineer department) commonly would agree that as long as we could keep tiling the plane to a sufficiently large extent( e.g use 100*100 tiles without conflict), then we blindly think these few basics tiles could tile the plane. So the undecidability is not too crucial...)

Comment: The book "Tilings and Patterns" by Grünbaum and Shephard has a section on Wang tiles. This might be a good (but outdated) starting point.

Comment: For some context, see author's earlier post, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/147374/coloring-in-lattice

Answer (score 6):

Original references (Wang's "Proving theorems by pattern recognition" and Berger's "The undecidability of the domino problem") are not very friendly. You may find some [review](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Egurevich/Opera/16en.pdf)s around, though.

I'll suggest you to take a look at Jarkko Kari's [website](https://users.utu.fi/jkari/) where you will find some introductory material and these [slides](https://www.univ-orleans.fr/lifo/Membres/Nicolas.Ollinger/talks/2008/03/turku.pdf) for some basic notions and references.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in Wang Tiling with Cellular Automata, which combines the two fields researched by Jarkko Kari as per Melquíades Ochoa, consider research in Erik Winfree's Algorithmic Tile Self-Assembly. He dives into Wang tiling and its specific applications in his Turing Complete (automata-esque) model. Here is a specific paper: https://authors.library.caltech.edu/22766/1/SAcircuits_DNA9_preprint.pdf