# Periodic Tiling of Wang tile

Tags: tiling

Without considering any aperiodic tiling, is there any established (or better efficient) algorithms that tries to determine whether a set of tile can tile Wang tile periodically (or better determine the number how often each tile is used)? 
For some context:
[coloring in lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147374/coloring-in-lattice)
[Reference for Wang Tile](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149565/reference-for-wang-tile)